# I'm new to Ubuntu and I can't seem to get this Curl command to work. How can I install nodejs 7.x on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, curl, sudo, discord

```
sudo apt-get update&&sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install curl
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -
```

and the curl command fails when trying to enter, says "bash: -d: command error

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, I dunno why but I had to type:

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
sudo apt-get purge nodejs npm
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

and that seemed to actually install 4.2, remove it, then install 7.x